# 404 error in Spring mvc app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have such mapping in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/newEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getOrganizerForNewEvent(@RequestParam("id") int organizerId){
    OrganizerEntity organizerEntity = organizerDAOService.findById(organizerId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("/newEvent");
    modelAndView.addObject("organizer", organizerEntity);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And such structure in webapp::

[image: And such structure in webapp:]

In dev tools request looks right:

[image: In dev tools request looks right]

But I get 404 error:
[image: But I get 404 error:]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error, because of incorrect view name

```
modelAndView.setViewName("/newEvent");
```

You should use name without slash:

```
modelAndView.setViewName("newEvent");
```

Comment: After change I get the same error, but message of error is:                          `/events/events/newEvent.jsp`

Comment: please, try to change "/newEvent" to "newEvent"